# How to check a comma separated value contains another Array

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list of processes:

```
List<Process > process= new List<Process >()
    {
        new Process { Id=1, Name="Process 01", CostCenter="1,2,3,4,5,6,7" , companyID = 1  },
        new Process { Id=2, Name="Process 02", CostCenter="1,2,3,4,10,11" , companyID = 1  },
        new Process { Id=2, Name="Process 03", CostCenter="1,2,5"         , companyID = 1  },
    }

    List<orderDetails> process= new List<orderDetails>()
    {
        new orderDetails{ Id=1, Name="order 01", CostCenterId="1" , companyID = 1  },
        new orderDetails { Id=2, Name="order 02", CostCenterId="2" , companyID = 1  },
    }
```

I need check, in order, if all any `CostCenter`s with the ID `1` or `2` are defined in the processes.

I've tried this code but it didn't work:

```
    var orderDetails = db.OrderDetails.Where(c => c.OrderId == order.Id);
    var orderCostCenter = orderDetails.Select(c => c.CostCenterId).ToArray();

    var listProcess = process.where (c=>c.companyID  == 1 &&
                  c.CostCenter.split(',').containt(orderCostCenter)).firstorDefault();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: First of all provided code will not compile. Can you fix it please?

Comment: Please provide expected output of the function you are trying to write, and give a few examples. Add this information to your question. If you cannot solve your simple use case with pen and paper, don't start writing code.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear and this should be messy to contain in comments. As I understand, you are looking for processes where all order details' CostCenterId is contained. If so:

```
var processes = process
    .Where(p => 
         orderDetails.All(d => $",{p.CostCenter},"
             .Contains($",{d.CostCenterId},")));
```

Comment: My question i need get one process Which contain cost Center from order Details list.?

Comment: My question i need get one process Which contain cost Center from order Details list.?                
I tried the example above but it was not solved  and return this error  ":                                       LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String Format(System.String, System.Object)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @WaleedAl-akrabawe, Your code had nothing to do with LinqToEntities, you should have specified that. You can go without string interpolation provided you add prefix, suffix commas to your values.